# Bootstrap-4 Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have four buttons in my page each of them open up the same modal.
All the buttons have the following structure.

```
<div class="card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#target-modal">Button -1
   <p class="status" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>
```

The modal contains a `<form>` , the elements in the form will slightly differ for each button (change in the no. of elements in the form will be handled at the backend using Laravel).

For now, I'm trying to achieve a functionality as in, when the form is filled and clicked on `submit`, I would like to identify which button out of the four opened up the modal and make `.status` to `display: block` to that button only and close the modal. This process should repeat for all the four buttons.

With the help of `show.bs.modal` I'm able to identify which button opened the modal. But I would like to know this result on click of `submit`.

Here is a quick [JS fillde](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqadwxf2/28/) to my code.

If anyone could solve this for me, it'll be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is that when `show.bs.modal` event is triggered on the modal, you can retrieve the DOM node of the button that triggered the showing through the `event.relatedTarget` object. Store this in the modal via the `.data()` method available in jQuery.

When the form submit event is triggered within the modal, you simply fetch the DOM node from the data object of the modal:

```
$('#target-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // Store the button that opened the modal
    $(this).data('from-button', e.relatedTarget);
});

$('#target-modal form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var triggerButton = $('#target-modal').data('from-button');
    $(triggerButton).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

A proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#target-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Store the button that opened the modal
  $(this).data('from-button', e.relatedTarget);
 });
 $('#target-modal form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var triggerButton = $('#target-modal').data('from-button');
  $(triggerButton).css('font-weight', 'bold');
  
  $('#target-modal').modal('hide');
 });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 150px;
  
  /* Only used to circumvent limitations in StackOverflow's code snippet */
  background-color: #4aa !important;
  
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.status {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom:-20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#target-modal">Button -1
<p class="status"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>

<div class="card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#target-modal">Button -2
<p class="status"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>

<div class="card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#target-modal">Button -3
<p class="status"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>

<div class="card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#target-modal">Button -4
<p class="status"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div id="target-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <form>
                              <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>                                                    <input type="text" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" required>
                              <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                              
                              <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="">Submit</button>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the solution @Terry :)